# EXCEL: Track consecutive weekly rise

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to track attendance and see if the individual has increased or decreased on weekly basis.  I want it to show whether they have increased/decreased.  The Q and R cells need to show either "1", "2" or "3 or more" only.  What's the best formula to use for this?

The spreadsheet is ongoing so want to be able to update it weekly. Is it possible for it to auto update each time I add a new column(week) or do I need to input the headers for the whole academic term and hide them for the formula to work??

[image]

Comment: What are the expected results for your current screenshot?

Comment: i want "successive rise" to show the count if a student has increased consecutively over the period of 1-3 weeks. The "successive fall" should also show the count but of the consecutive decrease over the period of 1-3 weeks.  So if its 1 week it'll show "1", 2 weeks then "2" and "3+" for 3 or more

Comment: so the expected output in Q2 & R2 is 1 or 0 (since the rise and fall is not consecutive) ?

Comment: It will be one or the other. So Q2 should be 1. Q4 and Q5 should return "2" as its now 2 consecutive weeks increase